# Headers in column using dojo

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

Is there a way to bring headers in the column and on click of the header, the attributes associated with the header in a different column using Dojo?

Thanks
Kumar

Answer (score 1):

you can use the event onHeaderCellClick

```
onHeaderCellClick: function() 
{
    console.log("do what you want");  
}
```

to add the header, you can do it easily in declarative way like this:

```
<table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th field="fieldName" width="200px">Column Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

If you are using declarative way you can use the attribute onHeaderCellClick to your table, onHeaderCellClick="func" call function func().